# Ruby ternary - warning: string literal in condition

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

This code works as expected:

```
if phrase.last.eql? "?" ? true : false
  true
else 
  false
end
```

but this code using the Ruby ternary operator:

```
phrase.last.eql? "?" ? true : false
```

gives the following error:

> warning: string literal in condition

Do I need to escape the `"?"` somehow?

Comment: A reminder to readers that Ruby has three ways of testing for equality:
`puts "#{5 == 5.0}, #{5.eql?(5.0)}, #{5.equal?(5.0)}" # => true false false`.  `true` because the values are the same, `false #1` because the values are different types, even though they are (`=`) equal, `false #2` because the values have different `object_id`'s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without parentheses, ruby is interpreting it as

```
phrase.last.eql?( "?" ? true : false )
```

which explains the message "warning: string literal in condition".

To fix this, use parentheses on the parameter:

```
phrase.last.eql?("?") ? true : false
```

Of course, in this case using the ternary operator is redundant since this is the same as simply

```
phrase.last.eql?("?")
```

Answer (score 2):

write as below :

```
phrase.last.eql?("?") ? true : false
```

Example :

```
2.0.0-p0 :023 > x = "a"
 => "a" 
2.0.0-p0 :024 > x.eql? "?" ? 1 : 2
(irb):24: warning: string literal in condition
 => false 
2.0.0-p0 :025 > x.eql?("?") ? 1 : 2
 => 2 
2.0.0-p0 :026 >
```

Otherwise `x.eql? "?" ? 1 : 2` is interpreted as `x.eql?("?" ? 1 : 2)`. Now in Ruby except `nil` and `false` all objects are `true`. Thus here `"?" ? 1 : 2`, `"?"` always will be `true`, so you got a warning for it. Putting a *ever truth value* in the *conditional test,* has no meaning, and *the same warning is being thrown to you fro Ruby interpreter.*